# Unity3d Android/Windows app integration with a library

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, dll, elf

I have a Windows application built using unity3d. The same source code is also used to build an android app. And for this app to access a remote database, I created a Restful service available as a .dll

My question is, is there a way my unity3d based android app use this .dll? I read about ELF32 formats. Not sure how to generate one.

I have the source code for the .dll and ideally I would like a common library to be used/called by both my windows/android app. But am not sure about a common format. Any ideas ?

Comment: You can rewrite your http requests in C# as a class.

Comment: Any other common library methods possible ?

Comment: You can call your dll from C# with pinvoke, but you would probably have to build a second version of the dll for android or rewrite it in java.